# What's the difference between adding Java Script libraries as npm dependencies or simply including them in HTML?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Looking at `npm` [starred packages](https://www.npmjs.org/browse/star) I see that some projects like **Grunt**, **lodash** or **underscore** are avaliable.

I've always used these in the classic way:

```
<script src="js/lib/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

What makes it different and how would I use them obtained within the `node_modules` packages?

Comment: node module packages are intended to be used with application made in nodejs and not other web based applications. As you add reference in .Net project or add jar in your classpath in java application, similarly to use a particular functionality we use npm to add modules to our nodejs application. Hope I cleared your question.

Comment: It cleared and opened my mind. As node.js isn't only about web development and is JavaScript from server side, having such makes sense.

Comment: then adding it as answer, please mark the same. thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I think you might answer too, it was *you* how clearly ***knew it***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On one hand, `npm` is a Node tool made to install packages for Node. Packages are collections of modules. And in Node, modules are loaded with a `require` call, which is a global function made available by Node.

On the other hand, `<script>` is the basic mechanism used in browsers to load JavaScript code.

This may seem mutually exclusive, but `npm` can be also used to install packages that are designed to run *both* in Node and in a browser. In this case we use Node's `require` to load a module from the package in Node, but we can use `<script>` or Browserify or RequireJS to load the same module in a browser. What method to use in the browser really depends on how the package was designed. You have to read the doc to know or read the source code if the doc is not good. I've designed a `npm` package that works this way. You can use Node's `require` to load it in Node and use RequireJS to load it in a browser.

`npm` can even be used to install packages that are designed to run *only* in a browser. In this case, `npm` is just a convenient delivery and dependency mechanism. I have another package designed this way. It comes with a prominent note that it is not made to run in Node. This is an accepted usage of `npm` and there are currently proposals ([here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4321) and [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4561)) to make `npm` even better at handling this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 1):

node module packages are intended to be used with application made in [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) and not other web based applications. As you [add reference in .Net project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx) or [add jar in your classpath](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/10/5-ways-to-add-multiple-jar-to-classpath-java.html) in java application, similarly to use a particular functionality we use [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/) to add modules to our nodejs application.

As node.js isn't only about web development and is JavaScript from server side, having such makes sense.

Comment: You can consume npm modules in the browser using browserify.

Comment: @m90 That makes another answer :)

Comment: browserify does not allow you to consume npm modules, but it allows you to have your app modules structured and maintained by npm and later you can use browserify to get all the required scripts in a single file. e.g. you use jquery, angular and bootstrap in your app you will have 3 script tags. If you use browserify you will write three require tags and have your app coded and your modules are managed with npm. Once you are ready with your app you will use broserify and it will remove all the require tags and replace them with single script tag and combine all the required js in single file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add JS dependancies in your html and use a npm like approach you should check out bower.

http://bower.io/

It has the same idea

```
npm install packageName
```

except it's

```
bower install packageName
```

Also with the --save and --save-dev versions of the install

Bower grabs the latest code from github, and you can specify versions as well.

Instead of package.json you have a bower.json, so if you are given a project with empty dependancies:

```
bower install
```

Then bower will go and grab the dependancies also specified versions and boom you are off! You have a bower_components directory that holds your entire dependancy tree.

npm for the frontend!